# Cannot display data split values from Arduino into kivy window

Tags: python-3.x, arduino, kivy

The left column represents temperature data, and the right column represents humidity data. I can split the data from the Arduino to Python. But when I run it in Python, I can only display the humidity data. However, the temperature data should also appear in the middle of the screen. Why is the temperature data not displaying on the screen?

[image: Arduino data from serial monitor]

[image: Python program]

Here is the code in Python:

#### File test.py

```
import serial
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import mainthread
import threading

class NaviWindow(Screen):
    temp_text = StringProperty("")
    humid_text = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NaviWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        threading.Thread(target=self.tm).start()


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NaviWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        threading.Thread(target=self.hm).start()


    def tm(self):
        while (1):
            with serial.Serial('COM4', 9600) as ser:
                data = str(ser.readline().strip().decode('ascii'))
                temp = data.split("|")[0]
                ser.close()
                self.update_temp(temp)

    def hm(self):
        while (2):
            with serial.Serial('COM4', 9600) as ser:
                data = str(ser.readline().strip().decode('ascii'))
                humid = data.split("|")[1]
                ser.close()
                self.update_humid(humid)


    @mainthread
    def update_temp(self, temp):
        self.temp_text = temp

    def update_humid(self, humid):
        self.humid_text = humid


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kys = Builder.load_file("test.kv")

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

#### File test.kv

```
WindowManager:
    NaviWindow:

<NaviWindow>:

    Label:
        size: 75, 50
        size_hint: 1, 1
        text: root.temp_text

    Label:
        size: 75, 50
        size_hint: 0.7, 0.7
        text: root.humid_text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got some basics wrong. `__init__` is being defined two times, so only one of them will run. And you really don’t need two threads to split one string into two.

Try it like this:

```
class NaviWindow(Screen):
    temp_text = StringProperty("")
    humid_text = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NaviWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        threading.Thread(target=self.tmhm).start()

    def tmhm(self):
        while (1):
            with serial.Serial('COM4', 9600) as ser:
                data = str(ser.readline().strip().decode('ascii'))
                ser.close()
                self.update_values(data.split("|"))


    @mainthread
    def update_values(self, data):
        self.temp_text = data[0]
        self.humid_text = data[1]
```

Comment: you are wellcome